# How to get serial number of USB-Stick

Tags: c#

```
ManagementObjectSearcher theSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'");
foreach (ManagementObject currentObject in theSearcher.Get())
{
    ManagementObject theSerialNumberObjectQuery = new ManagementObject("Win32_PhysicalMedia.Tag='" + currentObject["DeviceID"] + "'");
    MessageBox.Show(theSerialNumberObjectQuery["SerialNumber"].ToString());

}
```

How do I get the internal serial number of a USB-Stick or USB-HardDrive?
If i insert Hp or SanDisk Pen Drive it will display correct and whole serial number but if i insert some other pen drive means it will display only the first digit of the serial number. Why the problem occurs I don't know so please make me correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ...

`currentObject["PNPDeviceID"]` instead of `currentObject["DeviceID"]`

**Edit :** Change your query to `Select * From __InstanceOperationEvent Within 1 Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_DiskDrive' and TargetInstance.InterfaceType='USB'` and check..

Comment: what exception its throwing?

Comment: Management Exception was unhandled    Not Found

Comment: Download WMI Code Creator v1.0 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572, which will give you the query...